# show multiple messages in single notification

Tags: android

how to get multiple messages in a single notification .This is my following snippet

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);//

                Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, ConvActivity.class);
                PendingIntent nPendingInten = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_indietext_new);
                nBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.app_icon_indietext_new));
                nBuilder.setContentTitle(senderNum);
                nBuilder.setContentText(message);
                nBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                                .addLine(message)
                                .addLine(message))
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                 .build();


                TaskStackBuilder nStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                nStackBuilder.addParentStack(ConvActivity.class);

                nStackBuilder.addNextIntent(nIntent);
                nBuilder.setContentIntent(nPendingInten);

                NotificationManager nNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


                nBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

                //nNotificationManager.notify(0, nBuilder.build());
                nNotificationManager.notify(9999,nBuilder.build());
```

what is the procedure to get multiple notifications

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use different IDs 
    mNotificationManager.notify(ID, notifyDetails);

and set multiple messages in those ID's

Comment: i think this will be work to send multiple notificatons

Comment: I used it for multiple messages too.